# What instruction set does .NET target?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was reading an article a few days ago (I believe it was on MSDN), which said that the machine code generated by the .NET JIT Compiler does not target the Intel instruction set.  It said that: "Intel lost". Is this correct? If it does not target the Intel instruction set that what instruction set does it target?

I run the .NET framework on a PC with an Intel Quad core processor.  Therefore Intel must implement the instruction set that .NET targets.

Comment: Why don't you try to find the article, so you can check *exactly* what it said, and link to it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks.  I cleared my Internet History afterwards.  I spent time yesterday afternoon hunting for it but I could not find it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hm, recently I've read about Itanium architecture not supported as of .Net 4.5 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx: `The Itanium hardware architecture has a memory model weaker than that of the x86-x64. Itanium was supported by the .NET Framework until version 4.

Even though Itanium is no longer supported in the .NET Framework 4.5, understanding the Itanium memory model is useful when you read older articles on the .NET memory model and have to maintain code that incorporated recommendations from those articles.`

Comment: @MaxYakimets: So that *might* be relevant - although it's a year old. But this is the problem - until we know what the article actually said, we can't really provide useful feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> generated by the .NET JIT Compiler

The word "the" is quite inappropriate.  There are many jitters, each designed to generate code for `a` particular processor architecture.  Like the x86 and x64 jitters you'll use on a desktop machine, an ARM jitter for a mobile device, a PowerPC jitter used on an XBox.  And the Itanium jitter that "lost" because no processor design that requires the compiler to be smart enough to generate performant code has ever done well.  .NET also supports many embedded processors through the .NET Micro Framework but it uses an interpreter, not a jitter.

> Therefore Intel must implement the instruction set that .NET targets

A clear causality violation in that statement. .NET must target the instruction set with its jitter, not the other way around.  Intel does not pay attention to .NET.  Designing processors to target a specific VM has been done before (Harris for the Forth language, ARM for Java) but such processors never became main-stream.

The consistently winning strategy has been to develop processors that can still execute old programs without having to recompile them.  The x86 and x64 architectures have been very successful because of that.  This was done the same way it was done in .NET, Intel and AMD processors have a jitter built into the processor core that translate from the ancient x86 instruction set to an internal undocumented RISC-like one.

Comment: Additionally, the x86 and x64 jitters are likely to be [merged](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/30/ryujit-the-next-generation-jit-compiler.aspx) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the confusion rises because of the [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language). .NET compiles into CIL (formerly called Microsoft Intermediate Language or MSIL) which the "assembly" instruction set for .NET.

> CIL is a CPU- and platform-independent instruction set that can be executed in any environment supporting the Common Language Infrastructure ... Just-in-time compilation involves turning the byte-code into code immediately executable by the CPU.

The .NET framework distribution for the specific distribution (eg x86-x64) then translates the CIL code to native CPU instructions.

Hope I helped!